# Connect to remote hive database in DBeaver

Tags: jdbc, hive, apache-zookeeper, dbeaver

I'm aware of similar questions here however my setup is different.
There are 3 hops in my connection setup and the final connection is through Kerberos.

Today I SSH to the first computer through a CyberArk connection with a command like:
`ssh username@hopname@172.2.2.2@172.1.1.1`

This bring me to the first command prompt through which I connect to another machine with a ssh like: `ssh 172.3.3.3`

In this machine I can not login to hive REPL with the 'hive' command. I type 'beeline' which loads hive REPL fore me.

This is the setup for the SSH Tunnel:
[image: DBeaver SSH Tunnel Setup]

When I 'test tunnel configuration' this it appears to be successful:
[image: Successful SSH Tunnel connection]

Lastly I need to enter the main JDBC connection URL in the main page:
[image: Setup Page]

When I normally connect through beeline I can see that my connection is in this format:
jdbc:hive2://172.4.5.6:2400,172.5.6.7:2400,172.6.7.8:2400,172.7.8.9:2400,172.8.9.9:2400/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;sasl.qop=auth-conf;auth=KERBEROS;principal=hive/hadoop.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM

Therefore this is the string I put into the JDBC URL.
When I try to connect through this setup the progress bar goes across a third of the way and pauses for 30 seconds and then I receive this message:
[image: dbeaver connection error]

I'm not sure where the error logs are for more detail but looking around dbeaver files i couldn't find any.

Comment: are you using same password you use for Hue?

Comment: The CyberArk gateway is, in itself, a kind of SSH tunnel. And the connection string _does_ use the syntax of an SSH tunnel. So maybe you need to set up 2 tunnels: one through CyberArk gateway (as defined in DBeaver) that brings you to 2.2, and a second one to 3.3 (but how? seems tricky...)